# How to extract value from the OuterHTMLin python

Tags: python, regex, selenium

```
<a id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_c_hdetail_lblPat2" href="javascript:popupPatient(218809, '0');">CHATARPAL, LALITA</a>
```

I am trying to get the text (218809) from the outerHTML. earlier I wasdoing the same thing with AHK but now I am learning Python to do same thing.

Here is my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import re
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver.get("https://brightree.net/F1/0375/MBSNI/Receipts/Invoices/Invoice_Invoice.aspx?InvoiceKey=3729668")

wait=WebDriverWait(driver,10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_c_hdetail_lblSalesOrder2']")))

Target=driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_c_hdetail_lblPat2")
Get_Value=Target.get_attribute("outerHTML")
print(Get_Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Get_Value=Target.get_attribute("href")
Get_Value=re.findall('\d+', Get_Value)[0]
print(Get_Value)
```

use regex \d for finding digits , \d+ indicates one or more digits

Answer (score 0):

```py
# re is short for [r]egular [e]xpression
from re import match

# This is your example string from the question. The string contains both single
# and double quotes, so I used triple quotes to avoid needing to escape them.
string = """<a id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_c_hdetail_lblPat2" href="javascript:popupPatient(218809, '0');">CHATARPAL, LALITA</a>"""

# match any number of characters, then the method name, then capture the number.
pattern = r'.*?popupPatient\((\d+)'

# Get the first capture group from the regex and print it
print(match(pattern, string).group(1))
```